# Generalized Riemann Integrals

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

In my narrow knowledge of mathematical analysis, I know these two types:

$$
\int_a^{+\infty} f(x)\,\text{d}x := \lim_{c \to +\infty} \int_a^c f(x)\,\text{d}x\,, \quad \quad \quad \int_a^b f(x)\,\text{d}x := \lim_{c \to b^-} \int_a^c f(x)\,\text{d}x
$$

where in the first case $f : [a,\,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$, in the second case $f : [a,\,b) \to \mathbb{R}$.

From what I understand, the necessary condition (even if not enough) for the convergence of the integrals of the first type is that:

$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = 0
$$

otherwise it certainly doesn't converge. But as regards the second type, the same goes for $x \to b^-$, or is there some other reason that I have never found anything written about it?

For example, if I were to study the character of the integral:

$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}\,\text{d}x
$$

through a substitution $x = 1/t$ I would lead to an integral of the first type and therefore I would deduce that it doesn't converge. Could I have done the limit for $x \to 0^+$ directly or is it incorrect? Thank you!

Comment: $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$ is not a necessary condition for the convergence  of $\int_a^\infty f(x)\, dx$. Consider the characteristic function of the integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first type of improper integrals, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ is NOT a necessary condition for the convergence of $\int_a^\infty f(x)\, dx$. Consider the characteristic function of the integers. Other kind of examples can be constructed where $f$ is continuous.

For the second type of improper integrals, consider the integral $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt x}\, dx$$ converges but $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = \infty$$

Actually, if you require that $$\lim_{x \to b^-} f(x) = 0$$
that means that you could extend $f$ in a continuous way at $b$ as $f(b)=0$ and then $$\int_a^b f(x)\, dx$$ wouldn't even be an improper integral, it would be a regular Riemann integral.